# Firefox Addon to view/delete localStorage data

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage

Is there any Firefox Addon to View/Delete localStorage data?

The one on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firestorage/ is not working correctly.

Also in Firebug, if I do "localStorage" in the Console, it is showing me 0, even though there are like 5 items in my localStorage?

Comment: Just to add, I am using Firefox 4..

Comment: Updating to a current Firefox version would a good first step ([list of security issues fixed since Firefox 4](http://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox.html)). That might already be enough to make issues with extensions disappear.

Answer (score 2):

A great new **FireFox** Addon which is officially recognized by **Firebug** https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#FireStoragePlus is available from the Mozilla gallery: http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firestorage-plus/

This plugin extends Firebug to give you the functionality you need. As with Firebug itself, FireStorage Plus! is currently under heavy development so new features come out every couple of days...

It is stable and ready for use...